# null vs. undefined and their behaviour in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

So after a big argument/debate/discussion on the implementation of null and undefined in javascript I'd like somebody to explain the reasoning behind the implementation and why they differ in some circumstances.  Some particular points I find troubling:

- `null == undefined` evaluates to `true`
- `null + 1` equals 1 but `undefined + 1` equal `NaN`
- `if(!null)` evaluates to true and `if(null)` evaluates to false but `null == false` evaluates to false.

I've read the specification and I know how the results are reached, I'm looking for the paradigms and reasons that dictate this being the specification.  Some of these points, especially the second one, given the first, feel very inconsistent.

Comment: all I know is that null is an object. But this is great question. I'm following answers...

Comment: hej watch this: [JavaScript: The Good Parts, presented by Douglas Crockford](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQVTIJBZook)

Comment: `null != false` evaluates to true

Comment: null is not an object null and undefined are the only non object in js... that typeof null returns object was originally a bug

Comment: Related: [JavaScript undefined replaced with null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834062/javascript-undefined-replaced-with-null)

Comment: Guess type coercion is the culprit here.

Comment: @megakorre: somewhat correct, but `5` is not an object either; note that `5 !== new Number(5)`, where the latter is an object.

Comment: There may not be any real answer to this question. "Why is this corner of $LANGUAGE the way it is?" questions almost always come down to "in the original implementation it seemed like the most DWIM behavior" or "in the original implementation it seemed like the easiest behavior to produce". In the case of JavaScript, "the original implementation copied the behavior of Java for marketing reasons" is also a possibility.

Comment: @Zack, `null`, `undefined`, `Boolean` and `NaN` are **core** parts of JavaScript as a language, so I wouldn't describe these issues as "corner cases" especially because they deviate so drastically from what is typically expected from C-style languages.

Comment: @zzzzBov I'm glad somebody else feels their behaviour deviates from some of the older languages.

Comment: I would still describe *comparing them to each other* and *performing arithmetic on them* as corner cases.  Normal usage of `null` etc is to compare them to other things.  Also note that `===` and `!==` have much less surprising behavior, to the point where some coding standards say never to use `==` and `!=`.

Comment: @zzzzBov: These are interesting quirks but not terribly important for day-to-day JS development, so I'd say "corner cases" is reasonable.

Comment: @Endophage, the whole idea of `truthy` and `falsy` values in JS is drastically different from many common C-style languages. What it enables you to do as a programmer is *not care* whether you've got `""`, `false`, `NaN`, `undefined` or `null` because they're all `falsy`, and therefor probably not set to what you want.

Comment: Just do `undefined = null;`, and now they behave the same. ;)

Comment: @Zack, `var a = foo(); if (a == null) { a = bar(); } else if (a == undefined) { a = baz(); }` looks like legitimate code (it's not optimal by any means, but looks legit). It *should* be working code, but it doesn't because of the issues specified. Simple variable comparison should *never* have to be a "corner case".

Comment: I point you to what you said two comments up: `var a = foo(); if (!a) { a = bar(); }` would be properly idiomatic AIUI.  Distinguishing `null` from `undefined` was not something the original language thought was all that important.

Comment: Haha David +1 for kicking this one while it's down and crying :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The short and sweet version is that JavaScript was designed and implemented very rapidly by the Netscape team, and it had some inconsistencies such as the ones that you've pointed out.

The Internet Exploder team did its best to copy JS *exactly* and they did a damn good job of it to the point that the inconsistencies were copied as well. When Netscape went to get JS standardized as ECMAScript MS was a part of it and basically said that they weren't allowed to change the standard because it would break old code (existing systems inertia). The inconsistencies were standardized and that was that.

Douglas Crockford has [a very good series of talks about some of these issues](http://yuiblog.com/crockford/).

Comment: [Crockford videos](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/theater/video.php?v=crockonjs-1)

Comment: @Raynos, that's the one i was looking for, but I seem to have found another source as well.

Comment: To be fair, `NaN` not being equal to itself is IEEE 754's fault.

Comment: @RegDwight, I *hate* when people misuse `its` and `it's`, and there I go messing it up myself >,<

Comment: someone please kill IE >:(

Answer (score 8):

**First and foremost**, while plenty of languages get away without having two methods for such similar purpose, they do serve distinct though somewhat overlapping purposes in Javascript.  "Why have both?" has been asked here before, and I find that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834062/javascript-undefined-replaced-with-null/6834168#6834168) explains this fairly well. **TL;DR**: Javascript has certain language functions that produce *absent* values as opposed to *non-initialized* values:

- `delete`'d values
- non-existent properties in an object
- missing function parameters

As for the seeming contradictions in your question, they are actually quite easily explained by the spec.  *(I believe it can even be argued that the explanation is elegant, though there are probably those who would vehemently disagree.)*

Addressing each one separately:

> - null == undefined evaluates to true

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834062/javascript-undefined-replaced-with-null/6834254#6834254) for the best explanation of this.  In short, the [abstract equality comparison](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3) specification says that they are (non-strictly) equal.

---

> - null + 1 equals 1 but undefined + 1 equal NaN

The operator `+` functions as either the [unary +](http://es5.github.com/#x11.4.6) (numeric conversion) operator or [addition](http://es5.github.com/#x11.6.1) operator, but both route the arguments to the [ToNumber](http://es5.github.com/#x9.3) spec, which says:

> **Argument Type —  Result**
>   Undefined — NaN
>   Null — +0
>   Boolean — The result is 1 if the argument is true. The result is +0 if the argument is false.
>   Number — The result equals the input argument (no conversion).

In other words `null + 1` becomes `+0 + 1` and `undefined + 1` becomes `NaN + 1`, which is always `NaN`.

---

> - if(!null) evaluates to true and if(null) evaluates to false but null == false evaluates to false.

As you know `!` is the [Logical Not](http://es5.github.com/#x11.4.9) operator, and it performs a [ToBoolean](http://es5.github.com/#x9.2) **conversion** on the expression.  It is a type of truncation.

The [`if` statement](http://es5.github.com/#x12.5) (`if (expr)`) performs an implicit boolean comparison on *expr*.  So take a look at the type of *expr* in both of the above `if` statements:

- `if (!null)`: *expr* is `!null` which, given the result of the logical not operator (`!`), is a **boolean**.
- `if (null)` : *expr* is `null` which means no conversion was performed.

Since the **logical not** operator performs an actual conversion, the same thing happens in other cases as well, and is not actually a logical contradiction as you seem it to be:

- `if (!"" == !undefined)` = **true**
- `if ("" == undefined)` = **false**, of course.

Comment: This is a great answer... a more spec-filled version of mine, in a lot of ways. +1!

Comment: As I said I read the spec and I know why things works how they do as regards that.  I'm looking or the reasoning behind that implementation.

Answer (score 4):

They are best thought of as completely different objects used for different purposes:

**`null`** is used for "has no value." It is used pretty rarely by the language, but often used by the host environment to signify "no value." For example, `document.getElementById` returns `null` for nonexistant elements. Similarly, the IE-only property `onreadystatechange` for `HTMLScriptElement`s is set to `null`, not `undefined`, to signify that though the property *exists*, it's currently *not set*. It is generally good practice to use `null` in your own code, instead of `undefined`, and leave `undefined` for the following cases:

**`undefined`** is used for "isn't even set or doesn't even exist." It is the "default" in many cases, e.g. accessing an undefined property (like `onreadystatechange` for `HTMLScriptElement` in non-IE browsers), the default return value from methods without `return` statements, the default value of function parameters when the function is called with fewer arguments than it declares, and the like.

In this way, it's useful to think of `null` as a "valid value," just one signifying something special. Whereas `undefined` is more of a language-level thing.

Sure, there are some edge cases where these reasonings don't entirely hold; those are mostly for legacy reasons. But there is a difference, and it's one that makes some deal of sense.

---

As for your pain points in particular, they mostly arise from the evil of the `==` operator or type coercion:

- `null == undefined`: don't use the `==` operator, because it essentially is a mess of backward-compatibility rules that seemed intuitive at the time.
- `null + 1 === 1` vs. `undefined + 1 === NaN`: the `+` operator does type coercion to `Number` before evaluating. And `null` coerces to `0` (`+null === 0`) whereas `undefined` coerces to `NaN` (`isNaN(+undefined) === true`).
- `if (!null)`, `if (null)`, `null == false`: if evaluates the "truthiness" or "falsiness" of its argument, which has nothing to do with the mess of rules for `==`. `null` is falsy, and `!null` is truthy, but the rules for `==` don't let `null == false`.

Comment: `document.getElementById` returns `null` if it finds nothing. It's very common in Host objects for "no value"

Comment: Good example, yes. But I think it supports my point of it being a valid value signifying nothing, instead of a language-level thing... let me revise my post to lean more toward language than host.

Comment: actually the `==` is useful for checking both `null` && `undefined` because `null == undefined`. That very statement is the only valid use-case of `==`

Comment: Mmm, I know what you're saying is conventional wisdom, but instead I try to never be in a situation where my variables could be either `null` or `undefined` but I don't know which.

Comment: the only situation where they can be either but you don't know is user input. If your building libraries or anything else that interfaces with users or other developers you need to check for both. (Or be that annoying guy who's library crashes if you use `null` instead of `undefined`)

Comment: Fair enough. I guess I've pretty rarely written a function for which `null` was a valid input value; thus I end up only using `undefined`, and that only for optional argument defaulting.

Answer (score 1):

`null == undefined` does indeed evaluate to true, but `null === undefined` evaluates to false.

The difference in those two statements is the equality operator. Double-equal in Javascript will convert the two items to the same type before comparing them; for `null == undefined`, this means that the `null` is converted to an undefined variable before the comparison is done, hence the equality.

We can demonstrate the same effect with strings and integers: `"12" == 12` is true, but `"12" === 12` is false.

This example gives us an easier way to discuss your next point, about adding one to each of them. In the example above, adding 1 to the integer obviously gives `13`, but with the string `"12" + 1` gives us a string `"121"`. This makes perfect sense, and you wouldn't want it any other way, but with a double-equal operator, the original two values were reported as equal.

The lesson here is to always use the triple-equal operator in preference to the double-equal, unless you have a specific need to compare variables of different types.

Your final point demonstrates the fickle nature of `null` in general. It is a peculiar beast, as anyone who's ever tried to work with a nullable database field will tell you. Null has a very specific definition in computer science, which is implemented in a similar way across multiple languages, so the situation you describe is not a special Javascript weirdness. Null is weird. Don't expect it to behave like an alternative name for `false`, because it doesn't work that way. The built-in `infinity` value can behave in a similarly bizarre way, and for similar reasons.

Javascript does have its share of weirdness though. You might be interested in reading http://wtfjs.com/, which has entries for a whole load of strange things that Javascript does. Quite a few of them are to do with `null` and `undefined` (did you know it's actually possible to redefine the value of the built-in `undefined` object?!), and most of them come with an explanation as to what's actually happening and why. It might be helpful in showing you why things work the way they do, and will definitely helpful in showing you things to avoid! And if nothing else, it makes for a good entertaining read to see some of the abuses people have tried throwing at the poor language.

Comment: "you wouldn't want it any other way", i'd prefer that JS had a string concatenation operator like php's `.` so that there was a clear division in functionality.

Comment: @zzzzBov: hehe, yes, you're probably right. But in its absence, I'm glad that the `+` works consistently as a concat when my first argument is a string.