# {undefined} is {undefined:undefined} but {null} is null why?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I declared two variables player1 and player2.

```
const player1 = {undefined};
const player2 = {null};
```

**player1** returns **{undefined:undefined}** but **player2** returns **null** Why? what is the reason behind it?

Comment: The second line is a syntax error. The first works because `undefined` is a symbol, essentially a variable name, so the `{ undefined }` expression is valid.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [null vs. undefined and their behaviour in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000762/null-vs-undefined-and-their-behaviour-in-javascript)

Comment: @Filburt, I don't see how that other Q&A answers the question at hand.

Comment: How are these "returning" those results?  When I try to run just this code (appending `console.log` statements to observe the results), I get a syntax error.  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates what you are observing?

Comment: @Amodh your comment is unhelpful. JavaScript is one of the most heavily used languages on the planet.

Comment: @trincot I think it provides the understanding of undefined vs. null that is obviously missing.

Comment: @Filburt, that Q&A doesn't touch on anything that explains the behaviour mentioned in this question.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things going on here with `{null}`:

`const player2 = {null};` is a syntax error. The right hand side is evaluated as an object literal with shorthand property name, and a shorthand name must be an *IdentifierReference* (see ECMAScript specs on [Object Literal](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-object-initializer)). But `null` is a [reserved word](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-lexical-grammar.html#prod-ReservedWord) and is thus *not* valid as identifier reference.

`{null}` on its own -- where it is not part of a larger expression -- is interpreted as a statement block, and is valid. Imagine it as:

```
{
    null;
}
```

A console (like Chrome's dev console) may first try to parse an input like `{undefined}` or `{null}` as object literal. This works for `{undefined}` because it is valid syntax for an object literal (`undefined` is not a reserved word). When this is not possible (in the case of `{null}`) it may interpret it as a statement block.

When the console evaluates a statement (block) it may echo the value of the last evaluated expression. Thus the console may respond to `{null}` with `null`, just like it would respond to `{null; 1}` with 1. I suppose it was this behaviour that lead to the question.

If we would not use shorthand property names, then the syntax rules no longer require an *IdentifierReference*, but accept an [*IdentifierName*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#prod-LiteralPropertyName), and those can be reserved words.

So these object literals are OK:

```
const n = {null: null};
const t = {this: this};
const f = {false: false};
```

But these are syntax errors:

```
const n = {null};
const t = {this};
const f = {false};
```

While these are valid again, but as statement blocks:

```
{null}
{this}
{false}
```